# How can you download all non-obvious images with Beautifulsoup/Selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm making next little project to learn - it's what I'm trying to do past few days, without success. I want to make list of opals, their prices...and download their images from website. At end (probably) here are two ways: assign opals to images (in word or excel) or just save images with name of opal+price. I succeed at making list of name+price (using help I gained from previous topics), but I can't get into images. They don't have .jpg, here is not 'src' and when I 'extracted' example img link, it was wrong, too. Take a look:

> /storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.koroit-opal-company.com%2FWebRoot%2FStore15%2FShops%2F80300026%2F6364%2FF352%2FFF36%2F99BC%2F5F60%2F0A0C%2F6D0B%2FF3AC%2FIMG-8248VOLL_5_ECK.JPG&shop=80300026&width=**{width}**&height=2560

EDIT: 'code edited, too' - I managed to extract just the list of img list I needed.

Below is how img class of this website looks like:

[image]

And my code is below - it doesn't download images yet :(

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.koroit-opal-company.com/en/c/solid-opals'
page = requests.get(URL)
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36"}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(f'https://www.koroit-opal-company.com/en/c/solid-opals', headers=headers).text, "lxml")
# print(soup.prettify())

names = [n.getText(strip=True) for n in soup.select("div div div a h2")]
# print(names)
prices = [n.getText(strip=True) for n in soup.select("div div div h3")]
# print(prices)

for name, price in zip(names, prices):
    print(f"{name} {price}")

opal_list = soup.find('div', attrs = {'class':'content'})    #gives just fragment of website where opal imgs are
imgs = opal_list.find_all('img')
print(imgs)

example = imgs[0]
x = example.attrs['data-src']
print(x)

result = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'img' and
                       tag.get('class') == ['product-item-image'])

print(result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the API and all downloaded images ll be next to the executable file:

```
import requests


def get_info(page: int):
    url = f"https://www.koroit-opal-company.com/api/v2/products?sort=position-asc&resultsPerPage=12&page={page}&categoryId=551DDBD9-8AD4-229C-164A-C0A82AB9D825&locale=en_GB&shop=80300026"
    response = requests.get(url)
    for opal in response.json()['products']:
        img_link = 'https://www.koroit-opal-company.com' + opal['image']['url']
        print(opal['name'], opal['price']['formatted'], img_link)
        download_image(img_link, opal['name'])


def download_image(image_url: str, image_name: str):
    img_data = requests.get(image_url).content
    with open(image_name + '.jpg', 'wb') as handler:
        handler.write(img_data)


get_info(1)
```

OTPUT for page 1:

```
1,38 ct Boulder opal 70.00 € https://www.koroit-opal-company.com/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.koroit-opal-company.com%2FWebRoot%2FStore15%2FShops%2F80300026%2F6364%2FF352%2FFF36%2F99BC%2F5F60%2F0A0C%2F6D0B%2FF3AC%2FIMG-8248VOLL_5_ECK.JPG&shop=80300026
4,27 ct Black opal 3,300.00 € https://www.koroit-opal-company.com/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.koroit-opal-company.com%2FWebRoot%2FStore15%2FShops%2F80300026%2F5A8D%2F6108%2F2341%2FEB00%2F2803%2F0A0C%2F6D04%2FCDD2%2FIMG-7618VOLL_5_ECK.JPG&shop=80300026
4,52 ct Boulder opal 80.00 € https://www.koroit-opal-company.com/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.koroit-opal-company.com%2FWebRoot%2FStore15%2FShops%2F80300026%2F6364%2FF4E2%2FAFCE%2FF6ED%2F688E%2F0A0C%2F6D0F%2F3E17%2FIMG-8110VOLL_5_ECK.JPG&shop=80300026
0,85 ct Boulder opal 70.00 € https://www.koroit-opal-company.com/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.koroit-opal-company.com%2FWebRoot%2FStore15%2FShops%2F80300026%2F6364%2FF540%2FD8D2%2FE5C6%2F9854%2F0A0C%2F6D0B%2F05BA%2FIMG-8018VOLL_5_ECK.JPG&shop=80300026
13,14 ct Crystal opal 400.00 € https://www.koroit-opal-company.com/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.koroit-opal-company.com%2FWebRoot%2FStore15%2FShops%2F80300026%2F6286%2F56CC%2FED12%2F1E08%2FECEF%2F0A0C%2F6D0B%2F5AAC%2FIMG-9213_HOCH_MAI_22.JPG&shop=80300026
5,85 ct Boulder opal 80.00 € https://www.koroit-opal-company.com/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.koroit-opal-company.com%2FWebRoot%2FStore15%2FShops%2F80300026%2F6364%2FF59C%2F77B0%2FF735%2F05AF%2F0A0C%2F6D0F%2F8E4C%2FIMG-7990VOLL_5_ECK.JPG&shop=80300026
11,38 ct Boulder opal 2,400.00 € https://www.koroit-opal-company.com/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.koroit-opal-company.com%2FWebRoot%2FStore15%2FShops%2F80300026%2F594A%2F94B3%2FC880%2FF5AB%2F848B%2FC0A8%2F2AB9%2F4A53%2FIMG-8598VOLL_5_ECK.JPG&shop=80300026
2,41 ct Crystal opal 60.00 € https://www.koroit-opal-company.com/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.koroit-opal-company.com%2FWebRoot%2FStore15%2FShops%2F80300026%2F6364%2FF66A%2F867E%2F23D7%2FBF76%2F0A0C%2F6D0B%2F947B%2FIMG-8994VOLL_5_ECK.JPG&shop=80300026
6,94 ct Boulder opal 1,600.00 € https://www.koroit-opal-company.com/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.koroit-opal-company.com%2FWebRoot%2FStore15%2FShops%2F80300026%2F5AB9%2F3AB7%2F8F7A%2F659C%2FDDE4%2F0A0C%2F6D00%2FF73C%2FIMG-7672VOLL_5_ECK.JPG&shop=80300026
2,28 ct Crystal opal 70.00 € https://www.koroit-opal-company.com/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.koroit-opal-company.com%2FWebRoot%2FStore15%2FShops%2F80300026%2F6364%2FF4D7%2FAEFE%2FF74C%2F9A52%2F0A0C%2F6D0B%2F0587%2FIMG-8045VOLL_5_ECK.JPG&shop=80300026
1,48 ct Crystal opal 70.00 € https://www.koroit-opal-company.com/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.koroit-opal-company.com%2FWebRoot%2FStore15%2FShops%2F80300026%2F6364%2FF3B9%2F7E20%2F2E27%2FFB71%2F0A0C%2F6D0F%2FC782%2FIMG-8242VOLL_5_ECK.JPG&shop=80300026
11,29 ct Crystal opal 600.00 € https://www.koroit-opal-company.com/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.koroit-opal-company.com%2FWebRoot%2FStore15%2FShops%2F80300026%2F6335%2FB93C%2F9276%2F3389%2FB532%2F0A0C%2F6D0B%2F3404%2FIMG-5671VOLL_5_ECK.JPG&shop=80300026
```

UPDATE:
michalb93 asked how find api link:

1. Press "Show more" button with open dev tools on network tab
2. ctrl+f and search new opal's name, i search "2,75 ct Crystal opal"
3. After pressing Enter, u get list of requests which contain this name, u can see it in the attached screenshot.
   [image: CHROME NETWORK TAB]

Comment: Helpful! But, what in case if we'd have older website or we just didn't have API in some cases? How would downloading images look like?

Comment: @michalb93 almost every situation is unique and must be considered separately, so it is impossible to say in advance how to act. the function that in my code ll download any image from the link

Comment: how do you exactly know when you are able to use API method?

Comment: @michalb93 use f 12 then network tab, u can see requests from site

Comment: So, seeing all these 200s/requests mean I can try to access site's API?

Comment: @michalb93 not every site has an api, u have to understand which request gives u the information you need, whether it's an image or some kind of data. Next, u need to figure out what input data is needed for this request, it can be cookies, headers and/or payload

Comment: not all content is loaded statically with the page, it can be loaded dynamically via javascript for example

Comment: how exactly you did know that you can access `.com/api/v2/` site? I was searching for it in console, but found only something like `.com/storage/images/` (with json too)  or `/api/www/images` which isn't working

Comment: @michalb93 anwer updated